# How to use the method of undetermined coefficients to get complex version of binomial expansion?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, binomial-coefficients

Show that if $|z|<1$, and $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$, then $(1+z)^{\alpha}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty {\alpha\choose n}z^n$, where $${\alpha\choose n}=\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-n+1)}{n!}$$
I write $(1+z)^\alpha$ as $e^{\alpha\log(1+z)}$, and expand $\log (1+z)$ by Taylor expansion, and then expand $e^{\alpha\log (1+z)}$ by expansion of $e^x$. But I got stuck since I cannot think of nice way comparing the undetermined coefficients. Can some one help me out? Any hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

$$f(z) = (1+z)^\alpha = e^{\alpha\log(1+z)}$$
is holomorphic in the unit circle. It follows that
$$
f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} \, z^n
$$
for $|z| < 1$. It is easy to verify that
$$
f^{(n)}(0) = \alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-n+1) \, .
$$

Comment: Reading the question again I realize that it asks for *"... the method of undetermined coefficients"*, so this may not be the wanted answer.

Answer (score 0):

> The paper *[Composita and its properties](http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.2582)* by V.V. Kruchinin and D.V. Kruchinin presents techniques to obtain the coefficients of compositae of formal power series.
>
> They start with a given generating function $F(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}f(n)x^n$, consider various other functions $G(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}g(n)x^n$ and analyze the composition of $G$ with $F$.
>   \begin{align*}
> G(F(x))&=\sum_{k\geq 0}g(k)\left[F(x)\right]^k\\
> &=\sum_{k\geq 0}g(k)\sum_{n\geq k}F^\triangle(n,k)x^n
> \end{align*}
>   with the so-called *Composita* $F^\triangle(n,k)$
>   \begin{align*}
> F^\triangle(n,k)=\sum_{{\lambda_1+\cdots\lambda_k=n}\atop{
> \lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k\geq 1}}f(\lambda_1)\cdots f(\lambda_k)
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> In table 1 of this paper they state besides other information following building blocks
>
> \begin{array}{cc}
> F(x)&F^\triangle(n,k)\\
> \hline\\
> xe^x&\frac{k^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\\
> \\
> \ln(1+x)&\frac{k!}{n!}
> \begin{bmatrix}
> n\\
> k\\
> \end{bmatrix}\\
> \\
> e^x-1&\frac{k!}{n!}
> \left\{
> \begin{matrix}n\\k\end{matrix}
> \right\}\\
> \end{array}
>
> with $\begin{bmatrix}
> n\\
> k\\
> \end{bmatrix}, \left\{
> \begin{matrix}n\\k\end{matrix}
> \right\}$ the Stirling numbers of the first and second kind. Note the constant term of $F(x)$ is zero, so that the *[composition of generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Composition_of_series)* is valid.

Other related papers by V.V. Kruchinin are

- [Composition of ordinary generating functions](http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.2565)
- [Derivation of Bell Polynomials of the Second Kind](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.5065)